# How do I get the response of getaddr from a bitcoin node using socket programming in Bitcoin?

Tags: sockets, bitcoin, bitcoind

I want to get a list of bitcoin nodes from an existing node with an aim to get all the ip addresses of nodes currently running bitcoin. I have used socket programming to connect to an existing node and would like to get the address list in that node. So I wrote a message to get addresses in th node. However, the socket doesn't respond with the address list

```
    import socket;
    import time;
    import hashlib;
    import struct;
    import random;

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM);
    HOST = "5.182.39.200";
    PORT = 8333;

    def create_version_message():
        version = struct.pack("i",70015);
        services = struct.pack("Q",0);
        timestamp = struct.pack("q",int(time.time()));
        addr_recv_services = struct.pack("Q",0);
        addr_recv_ip = struct.pack(">16s",bytes(HOST, 'utf-8'));
        addr_recv_port = struct.pack(">H",8333);
        addr_trans_services = struct.pack("Q",0);
        addr_trans_ip = struct.pack(">16s",bytes("127.0.0.1",'utf-8'));
        addr_trans_port = struct.pack(">H",8333);
        nonce = struct.pack("Q", random.getrandbits(64));
        user_agent_byes = struct.pack("B",0);
        start_height = struct.pack("i",596306);
        relay = struct.pack("?",False);
        payload = version + services + timestamp + addr_recv_services + addr_recv_ip + addr_recv_port + addr_trans_services + addr_trans_ip + addr_trans_port + nonce + user_agent_byes + start_height + relay;
        magic = bytes.fromhex("F9BEB4D9");
        command = b"version" + 5 * b"\00";
        length = struct.pack("I", len(payload));
        checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(payload).digest()).digest()[:4];
        return magic + command + length + checksum + payload;

    def create_getaddr_message():
        magic = bytes.fromhex("F9BEB4D9");
        command = b"getaddr" + 5 * b"\00";
        payload = b"";
        length = struct.pack("I", len(payload));
        checksum = hashlib.sha256(hashlib.sha256(payload).digest()).digest()[:4];
        return magic + command + length + checksum + payload;

     sock.connect((HOST,PORT));
     sock.send(create_version_message());
     sock.recv(1024);
     time.sleep(5);
     sock.send(create_verack_message());
     time.sleep(5);
     sock.send(create_getaddr_message());
     sock.recv(1024);
```

Comment: Function create_verack_message()  is undefined in tour code.

Comment: thanks! actually i had not created the verack message and didn't transmit it earlier!

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow Bitcoin protocol.

- send version message
- receive version message from remote
- receive verac message from remote (you have to issue sock.recv twice)
- send verac message

After this connection is established and you can send getaddr message and process results recursively.

Comment: thank you! i had forgotten that i need to send a verack message again. thank you

Comment: hi, how do we know that how many bytes to receive for version  and how many for verac?

Comment: @PouJa Version field is 4  first bytes of of version advertisement message. The `verack` message is 24  bytes long of which 12 bytes after msg header are "verack" command. See https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#version and https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#verack